# creating marmotta archetype webapp error(new)

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, apache-marmotta

I am a new-bie to spring framework and maven tool. I am trying to create an Maven-archtype-webapp project in `Eclipse Kepler New version(Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819)`.

I created a new workspace, but when I am trying to create a new project, I am getting the following error:

```
creating marmotta archetype webapp has encountered a problem
```

In my case, the project is not created. I looked everywhere to find a solution in my case, but I'm unable to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to check the current 3.2.0 archetypes in Marmotta, which have been completely revised for the latest release.